# Android app requesting url twice when requested with url params

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, webview

I'm writing an android app that loads a webview, the javascript within (bootstrap) immediately changes location (window.location='blah') to a remote file(application_loader) which then loads the javascript and other resources that make up the app from a remote location.

The problem I'm having is that when the bootstrap file loads the application_loader file, I see the request getting made twice in my server, once as /application_loader.html, and once as /application_loader.html?device=android. The second one is the actual url I'm loading, so how come it also makes a request for the resource without the url params?